Column (data-type) for user-specified custom-ordering/priority of rows?
I am working on a webservice where users can specify processing rules. The user should be able to specify the order/priority of the processing rules, this obviously should be stored in the database.
I am wondering if MariaDB has some built-in support for such ordering columns, or whether I have to manually update all affected rows when the user moves a row from e.g. priority 8 to priority 2. In that case I would have to update the column for all in-between rows, which I would prefer not having to do manually.

Use linear unidirectional list or more complex list structure.

Can multiple rows be "priority 2"?  (Simple to do.)  Or do you imply shifting the current 2..7 to be 3..8?  (Messy, and won't perform well for million-rot tables.)
